# Next.JS requests API on every text change

Tags: next.js, frontend

```
export default function Home() {
 /** useState and all that

    const handleEnter = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        getRank();
      }
    };
  
  <input onKeyDown={handleEnter} />

    function getRank() {
      const str = searchText;
      const parsed = str.split("#");
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/info", { params: {username: parsed[0], tag: parsed[1]} })
      .then(function (response) {
        setRank(response.data)
        element.classList.add('out')
      }) .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }


  return (
    <div className="main">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <input className="input" type="text" onChangeText={(val) => {setSearchText(val)}} onKeyDown={getRank}></input>
    </div>
```

This is the code. Every time I edit the text on the input, it executes the "getRank()" function.
I want the getRank() function to be executed only when the "enter" key is pressed instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO, That question is as unclear as my future, please edit the question so we can understand you better

Comment: This kinda floats in the middle of nowhere: ```<input onKeyDown={handleEnter} />```. Also, in your actual return (what's rendered on the page), you call *getRank*, and not your actual *handleEnter* function. See: ```<input className="input" type="text" onChangeText={(val) => {setSearchText(val)}} onKeyDown={getRank}></input>```. Also, what is onChangeText? shouldn't that just be onChange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really try and fill out the code snippet appropriately so that we actually get a "real" insight into your code. What seems obvious to you, might not seem obvious to others. We have no insight into your application.

With that said, your ***handleEnter*** function is correctly written:

```
const handleEnter = (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    getRank();
  }
};
```

However, this input field that is defined straight afterwards: `<input onKeyDown={handleEnter} />`, makes no sense. It's not a part of the returned JSX.

And when you do return some JSX, you're not using your ***handleEnter*** function. Instead, you're calling ***getRank*** directly.

See this part of your code:

```
return (
  <div className="main">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <input className="input" type="text" onChangeText={(val) => {setSearchText(val)}} onKeyDown={getRank}></input>
</div>
```

Another thing that stands out to me is the ***onChangeText*** on your input field. As far as I know, the on change callback prop is ***onChange*** and **NOT** ***onChangeText***, seeing as it's a native input element and not a component with its own prop.